# Organizing JUnit tests

Tags: unit-testing, junit

In the past I would make a test suite per package, that would hold all of the tests in that package.
then I would roll up all of the package test suites into a master test suite, which would hold all of the package test suites.
Anyone know of a better idea?

Comment: Sounds good to me. What do you want to improve? Are you unsatisfied with that technique somehow?

Comment: just seeing if there are any better ideas, if any, always looking to improve :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your approach is a good starting point, your Test-suits are structured in the way of your code definition. You could also add additional test-suits to cover special functional behavior.

For Example if you need for your `addXXX()` Method a Controller/Model/Display(MVC-Pattern) out of different packages you should combine your `addXXX()`, `removeXXX()`, `updateXXX()` to a Test-suite like `modifyXXX()`. So you don't have all Classes of the packages tested, but only the Methods for one pack of funcionality.

Comment: This answer could use some greater explanation for those of us who don't already know the answer. Also that sentence that begins "For Example..." is extraordinarily hard to parse. Maybe better as 2-3 sentences.